# Phpmailer send bulk messages

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have this script to send emails to reciepients but i have a question. My code right now looks like this:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();

$email->From      = 'my_email_here';
$email->FromName  = 'Snaq';
$email->Subject   = $subject;
$email->Body      = $body;

foreach($emails as $mail) {
    $email->addAddress($mail);
}

if(!$email->Send()) {
    echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $email->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    $_POST = array();
}
```

So, my question is this: This script works perfectly and send the emails to the reciepients but, what happens if i want to send it to say, 500 emails? Spam? How to prevent that? I've been searching and found some possible solutions like generating a single email and then use the $mail->AddBCC() to let the mail server to handle the rest (sends copys of that email). Is this doable? I've found another solution that was making a script running in background (with cronjobs if im not mistaken). What is the best solution to do this? Im not familiar with cronjobs so if there was another simpler solution would be great.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely want to use cron - doing it through a web page load is prone to errors, timeouts, and security issues. When you've got that sorted out, look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). It really helps to be on good terms with your mail server and ISP!

Comment: @Synchro, tks for your answer. i've been googling for cronjobs and i think i can manage something. I'm thinking about inserting the emails into a queue table on the database and divide those emails say 50 per hour. and use a cron to run the send emails every hour. Do you have any advice? tks again =)